# ElasticSearch: Does optimizing indices block document imports?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I am considering optimizing one of my indices: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-optimize/

The documentation doesn't mention if optimizing an index interferes with current import processes. Does it block imports, or only impact the efficiency of imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still index documents while optimizing an index. But make sure you really need to optimize, since it's a really expensive operation and during the process the index size will grow to double the initial size, since the index is going to be rewritten to new segments. That's why the optimize operation was [renamed to forceMerge in lucene](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/11/21/simon-says-optimize-is-bad-for-you/), because optimize was somehow making people think it would be something to run daily or weekly to have a healthy index. That's not the case; on the contrary it makes sense to run optimize only if you have an index that you want to archive, where you are not going to index documents anymore.

If as you said you plan to optimize an index while indexing, well that doesn't make much sense and won't help a lot.